# Troubleshooting Beancount Error: Balance Mismatch in Simple File

Tags: beancount

with a simple beancount file like this:

```
2023-01-01 open Assets:Test
2023-01-01 open Expenses:A
2023-01-01 open Expenses:B

2023-01-01 *
    Assets:Test
    Expenses:A 57.7 USD
    Expenses:B 324.72 USD
    Expenses:A 268.44 USD

2023-01-02 balance Assets:Test -650.86 USD
```

When i ran the bean check command with file, i got this error:

```
Balance failed for 'Assets:Test': expected -650.86 USD != accumulated -650.9 USD (0.04 too little)

   2023-01-02 balance Assets:Test                                     -650.86 USD
```

Expected to happen: balance to be 650.86 USD
What acutally resulted: balance to be 650.90 USD

Answer (score 1):

Change your first transaction to `Expenses:A` to `57.70 USD`. The first use gives the precision that is being used for the account in a transaction.

```
2023-01-01 *
    Assets:Test
    Expenses:A 57.70 USD
    Expenses:B 324.72 USD
    Expenses:A 268.44 USD

2023-01-02 balance Assets:Test -650.86 USD
```

More details on precision handling can be found in [the documentation](https://beancount.github.io/docs/precision_tolerances.html).